# How to add menu to middle of html page?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

This is the code of the menu which i want to add in the middle

```
<div id="menu">

    <ul>
    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Babyboy.html">Baby Boy</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="Boybodysuits.html">Bodysuits</a></li>
        <li><a href="Boyonepiece.html">One Piece</a></li>
        <li><a href="Boyshoes.html">Shoes</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="Babygirl.html">Baby Girl</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="Girlbodysuits.html">Bodysuits</a></li>
        <li><a href="Girlonepiece.html">One Piece</a></li>
        <li><a href="Girlshoes.html">Shoes</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Accessories.html">Accessories</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
```

And this is the CSS code

```
#menu ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;}

#menu ul li{
    background-color:#404a7f;
    border:1px solid white;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-right:15px;
    font-family:Century Gothic;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:120px;
    height:35px;
    line-height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    position:relative;}

#menu ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    display:block;}

#menu ul li a:hover{
    background-color:#191d33;
    border-radius:10px;}

#menu ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;}

#menu ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;}
```

So I want to make this menu appear in the middle of the page horizontally but I don't know how to do this and in a simple way. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS file:

```
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Change `#menu ul ul position` from `absolute` to `relative`.

```
#menu ul ul{
    position:relative;
    display:none;}
```

See the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2j5k37mw/

or if you want to center it all in one line, add this to your CSS file:

```
#menu {
    bottom: 0;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: it became in the middle and they are below each other

Comment: Is that what you want?

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you mean. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: I want it to be like this [link](http://imgur.com/LgWJwz6)
I dii this by this code 
#menu{
 width:690px;
 margin:auto;}
But when i zoom out the contact us item become under home

Comment: Sorry, i thought this was done and didn't log in. Did you fix it?